# No Outgoing, Key or Incoming references tab in DotMemory

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, dotmemory

I'm completely new to DotMemory. The only memory profiler I've used in the past was Valgrind, so I'm probably overlooking something trivial.

I'm working on trying to find memory leaks in an application we're working on, using the following tutorial: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/How_to_Find_a_Memory_Leak.html

While analyzing the comparison of snapshots, the tutorial shows the following screenshot:

[image]

While, on my screen, there is no "Outgoing", "Key" or "Incoming" references tab at all:

[image]

Am I overlooking something, or is there a difference between versions? How do I get a list of references and retention paths?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several objects of type "Settings_Part" in your snapshot, so you see an "Object set" view, which allows analyzing a set of objects. To see an "Object" view from the help article you need to scope to one object. To do this, use "Instances" view to see all objects instances in the set and choose one to analyze. Or if you not sure that all of these objects retained in the same way, you can use "Similar retention" view first to split these objects into clusters by different retention path, scope to one of them and then, use "Instances" view as described above.

Comment: It can be so simple in the end :) Thank you so much!